# Slow compilation using Texpad on MacOS (LuaLaTeX). How to speed up compilation?

Tags: luatex, compiling, texpad

Is there a way to speed up compilation on Texpad? When I compile this particular `*.tex` file the compilation lasts about 4sec in TexShop, when I compile it in the Texpad its about 15sec.

Comment: Is TeXPad set to use the same TeX Distribution as TeXShop?

Comment: Yes, both have this path `/Library/TeX/texbin`.